# Inequalites of triangle side with $abc = 1$

Tags: geometry, inequality, triangles, sum-of-squares-method, holder-inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be the sides of a triangle with $abc=1$.
Prove that $$ \frac{\sqrt{b+c−a}}{a} + \frac{\sqrt{c+a-b}}{b} + \frac{\sqrt{a+b−c}}{c} \ge a+b+c $$

Comment: $abc$ is multiplication of the length of the sides?

Comment: I saw this question someplace earlier... may be in older Math.SE.

Comment: @Deddy Have you tried anything?

Comment: use the Ravi substitution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Holder $\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{b+c-a}}{a}\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2(b+c-a)^2\geq(a+b+c)^3$.

Hence, it remains to prove that $abc(a+b+c)\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}a^2(b+c-a)^2$, which is

$\sum\limits_{cyc}(a-b)^2(a+c-b)(b+c-a)\geq0$, which is obvious.